# MongoDB aggregation by week, starting on sundays. How to merge week 0 to week 52 of the previous year?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, datetime, week-number

So, i have an MongoDB aggregation that aggregates data from DB by weeks.
According to documentation of $week aggregation:

> Returns the week of the year for a date as a number between 0 and 53.
>
> Weeks begin on Sundays, and week 1 begins with the first Sunday of the year. **Days preceding the first Sunday of the year are in week 0**.

I need to connect data from this week 0 to week 52 of previous year.

P.S. it is unknown in script wheter week 0 exists and will it be used or not

I used a "crutch" which parses data array and then migrates data from week 0 (it if exists) to week 52 by itself.
But it can lead to bugs when working with arifmetical figures, for example: average, min, max. And this will lead to a lot of coding and refactoring.
So, is it possible to unite data from week 0 to week 52 without crutches ?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you can provide sample documents and expected output